# cdc when source system is sql server azure/standard 2008+

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Let us say my target staging db/data warehouse is sql server 2008+ enterprise. However, my source systems are sql server azure/standard 2008+. Can I still exploit CDC? As far as I understand, I cannot as I have to turn CDC on in the source systems and it is only available for eneterprise editions. Is this correct? I am also curious what happens if the transaction log is truncated. Thanks.

Comment: You can build your own CDC solution with triggers and log tables if you wish.

Comment: I know but it is fairly complicated/error proned etc. and does not answer my question (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just googled it and... if you need this for replicating into a data warehouse you probably only need *change tracking* https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519(v=sql.105).aspx. This http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/ says change tracking *is* available in Azure.

I don't see any specific info anywhere about whether change tracking uses the transaction log, but this info is in one of the links:

> The tracking mechanism in change data capture involves an asynchronous
>   capture of changes from the transaction log so that changes are
>   available after the DML operation. In change tracking, the tracking
>   mechanism involves synchronous tracking of changes in line with DML
>   operations so that change information is available immediately.

Comment: Thanks. I am only interested in cdc.

Comment: Well don't lose sight of your original problem

Comment: So is the answer NO in your opinion? That's what I am after. I have a consultancy which suggest using CDC with a SQL Server Azure source. IMHO this would not work as CDC has to be enabled on the source system which needs to be SQL Serevr 2008+ Enterprise. I am happily using SSIS and SQL standard at the moment ...

Comment: Sorry I can't give you a definitive answer on this. The Azure link above doesn't mention CDC at all. Perhaps an official MS group can help (though it's reasonable for you to get a definitive answer here also). Maybe you could try on DBAStackExchange?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's why I tried SO (-: To clarify - you agree with me that CDC is impossible if the source system is not enterprise - correct?

Comment: Yes I agree you can only use it in Enterprise edition, based on these two links: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7726.sql-server-change-data-capture-cdc.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx